# I am trying to count the occurrences of name of actor/actress but not including the current year into a new column star_value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe looks like this:

[what dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o935Z.png)

For example for actor Adam Driver the column will look like this after the function is called.

[What I am trying to get- with new star_value column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUwkK.png)

I am only able to print out list for each row but I don't know how to iterate through each row based on index for name and index on year to count.

```
star= star_df.loc[:, ['name', 'year_film']]
star_lst = []
count = 0
                                                                    
for i in range(len(star)): 
    stars = [star.loc[i, 'name'], star.loc[i, 'year_film']]
    for stars[1] in stars[i]: 
        if stars[0] in stars[i]: 
            count += 1
        else: 
            count == 1
#return count 

print(count)
```

Comment: please run `df.head(10).to_dict()` and copy and paste the output here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in df.index:

if stars[0] in stars[x]: 
    count += 1
else: 
    count == 1
```

more on index selecting at [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Hi, I tried this out with a test df. I am not able to count when the Name appears again in the next row

Comment: def star_val(s):
    count = 0 
    for x in df.index:
        for i in df.index: 
            if df.Name[x] and df.Year[x] in df.index: 
                if df.Year[i] > df.Year[x]: 

                    count += 1
                else: 
                    count == 1
    return count 
df["star_value"] = df.apply(star_val, axis=1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).